# converting hexadecimal number into decimal number using awk script

Tags: awk

I can convert hexadecimal number stored in a variable to decimal number in shell using:

```
$ x=08BA
$ echo $x | awk '{print strtonum( "0x" $1 )}'
2234
```

But when i writing awk script in a file to perform same task using following code giving error.

```
program:
x=08BA
system("echo $x | print strtonum( "0x" $1 )");
```

Error message is:
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

kindly provide solution

Comment: Anything wrong with `print strtonum( "0x" x )` ? `sh: 1` - you are executing you script as shell script, not awk script. `program:` - what does "program:" mean?

Comment: so in your 2nd block of code, that is an `awk` script that calls `system` to open a shell to use a `pipe` to call `awk` again? Why? Just do you conversion inside of `awk` as you do in your first example. And in any case, the `$x` in `echo $x` will be empty in that context. Good luck.